# Onsen 2 ui navigation with parameters

Tags: onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I know how to get the parameters in Onsen 1 like

```
$scope.navigator.getCurrentPage().options.param1
```

But I am unable to find any useful document or source to get the ons-navigator data in Onsen 2. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself `$scope.navigator.topPage.data` will have all the parameters sent thought the navigator.